# C - Creating parallel backgrounding thread

Tags: c, multithreading

I got some question about threading in C. I have a task, that I like to be activated all maybe 20ms. The task is a simple function that perform a request for a procadress on kernel32 The result is a simple true or false.

My problem is, I want to be that the function is called every 20ms or more, parallel while my application is running and if the result is true, the application should be register it.

Is there any simple possilibity? I tried with pthread, but I will pause my main application. The functions calls should be in the background and important 100% parallel.

Hope you did understand it, I don't want code, just gimme the clue for a right hint!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such a thing "100% parallel", unless you have a 100% parallel hardware running the tasks.

Comment: My cpu has 8 threads(and fx), it's just for my computer

Comment: There are only really a few main category of solutions. 1. Your main thread can periodically poll the result. 2. The main thread waits on an event from the child thread indicating that the result is ready (note that this is the even driven model and the main application can also service other events). Which one you choose depends on how you want/need your program to be structured. It sounds like you may want the second approach. There are many ways to do that including `pipe`+`select`, `pthread_cond_wait`, etc.

Comment: You could try creating individual pthreads and (assuming you have a multi-core computer) use `pthread_setaffinity_np()` if it's available to set each thread to its own core.  Crude, not portable, and definitely not good practice, but potentially a solution.